# Unity date applet crashes all the time (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: unity, 13.04

The default date applet which comes in Unity crashes all the time. When I click on it, nothing will appear (some tiny black window will appear). I restarted my system couple of times, still it didnt work. How to fix it ? I am using Ubuntu 13.04

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling "Coming events from evolution calendar" in Time & Date Settings (Clock section) fixed this.